# What is the definition of a "variable"?

Tags: c++, variables, language-lawyer

The standard states that

> An entity is a value, object, reference, function, enumerator, type,
>   class member, template, template specialization, namespace, parameter
>   pack, or this.

This implies that a *"variable"* is not an entity.

But further in the standard said:

> Every name that denotes an entity is introduced by a declaration.
>   Every name that denotes a label is introduced either by a goto
>   statement (6.6.4) or a labeled-statement (6.1).

and

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than
>   a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name denotes
>   the reference or object.

I'm assume from this two quotes that a *variable* is a name.

It is because the *variable* is introduced by declaration of reference and every name that denotes entity introduced by a declaration. **But what does a *variable*'s name mean?** A *variable* is also a name by definition.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm assume from this two quotes that a variable is a name.

No, from the quotes you provided, a variable is an object or a reference which has a name.

> It is because the variable is introduced by declaration of reference and every name that denotes entity introduced by a declaration.

The declaration introduces both the variable (the object or reference), and its name. This doesn't imply that that variable is the name, just that both are introduced by the declaration.

Comment: Does you mean that the set of all variables is a subset of all entities?

Comment: @St.Antario: That's an odd way to put it, but yes, every variable is an object or a reference, and therefore an entity.

Comment: Some variables does not have a name. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the term variable is a bit ambiguous in this respect, but by looking at the various uses of the term variable in the c++ standard, it looks like a variable is a special kind of entity. It is either an object or a reference. However, not all objects or references are variables, only the ones introduced the way described in **[basic]/6**:

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than
>   a non-static data member or of an object. The variable's name, if any,
>   denotes the reference or object.

Note that some variables are unnamed, for example the parameter of the function f in the example below:

```
void f(int) {}

int main() {}
```

Comment: You DO realize that this question was asked about 13 months ago. I very much doubt that the OP is still around to accept the answer... And "unnamed arguments" are pretty much useless as "variables" - they are only useful as placeholders when you have functions that take arguments that aren't used, in which case it's a bit of a stretch to call that argument a variable.

Comment: It's not a stretch, the standard is clear about it. It even uses the words "if any" when referring to the variable's name.

Comment: And aside from being a placeholder [necessary], how would you actually USE such a thing?

Comment: You can't, but it is still a variable according to the c++ standard. It would be interesting to know if there are any other unnamed variables. I can't think of any example.

Answer (score 0):

The best simple definition I can think of is:
*a Variable is trio of name, address and type (usually implies a size).*

Originally it was meant to hold a changeable value but some languages allow this value to be constant (write once).

Comment: Variables don't *always* have to have addresses. Some can live entirely in registers.

Comment: Some variables does not have a name. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is, as you say, the name of "a something". That "a something" is either a reference (to another object) or an object. Note that object here does not infer "an instance of a class", so an object could be a char, array of int, or pointer to void.

This name is held by the compiler, and when code is generated, space somewhere is allocated for the variable [1], in a register or on the stack (local variables) or in "data space" (`static` or global variables). This gives the variable a location, an address (note that registers don't have addresses).

[1] Variables can also be eliminated if the compiler finds that the variable isn't used [or, sometimes replaced, when for example a loop optimisation is changed from one form of loop to another]

Comment: Some variables does not have a name. See the example in my answer.