# Follow-up: What exactly is a variable in C++14/C++17?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, standards

As the title suggests, [this question has been asked before.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2920773/4917725) However, the answers pertained to C++03/0x(11). C++11 (N3337) says this about variables:

[[basic]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic#6):

> A *variable* is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name denotes the reference or object.

This may imply that variables are essentially named objects/references.

However, in [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic#6)/[C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#6), that last sentence was changed to

> The variable’s name, **if any**, denotes the reference or object.

which implies that a variable does *not* necessarily have a name.

A different interpretation of the first sentence may suggest that a variable *is* a name, since a *name* denoting an object/reference is also introduced by a declaration of such entities. But the second sentence contradicts that notion with the phrase "variable's name". So, is *variable* now just a hypernym for *object* and *reference*, whether named or not?

Comment: pointer to a variable is not a name but the variable exist.

Comment: @vcloarec a pointer itself must have a name. An r-value produced by taking the address of a variable is not a variable.

Comment: Possibly answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/31234708, but not really a duplicate question, since that other question didn't ask about this aspect.

Comment: @George : I wanted to illustrate that a variable does not necessarily have a name.

Comment: @vcloarec "pointer to a variable is not a name but the variable exist." doesn't illustrate that. I'll admit to not knowing what the "if any" part actually means, but again, a pointer variable must have a name, and an r-value produced by taking the address of an object (pointer or not) is not automatically a variable.

Comment: @George : I aggree with you, the address of the object is not automatically a variable and a pointer variable must have a name. But, i think a object (a variable) mustn't  have to have a name. So that's why the "if any". An other example is the exception on the answer of Barry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This change was a result of [CWG 1769](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1769), addressing the status of exception objects bound to unnamed catch handler parameters:

```
catch (std::exception&) // <==
{ 
}
```

That is now a variable. This simplifies the conceptual model around exception objects.

The first sentence, which remained unchanged, is still the complete definition of the term *variable*.

Comment: So, all _declared_ objects and references (except references that are non-static data members), whether named or unnamed, are variables?